# The program is asking again and again of input of width ?What to do ? New in C language

Tags: c, cs50

The program is asking again and again of input of width ?What to do ? New in C language. Continuously asking for ("Enter the Width ") when i enters it it kept asking again and again.

---

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
    int height = 10;
    int width = 10;
    int width_Asterix = 2;

    printf("Enter the Height:");
    height = GetInt();

    for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the width: ");
        width = GetInt();

        for (int j = width ;j>0; j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        width--;
        for (int k = 0; k<width_Asterix; k++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        width_Asterix +=2 ;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask for the width inside a loop, if you don't want to do it again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should put this:

```
printf("Enter the width: ");
width = GetInt();
```

Outside of the for loop, between

```
height = GetInt();
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
```

In that way it is only asked once (outside the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Without you telling us more about your program, it appears that you are trying to print an [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) pyramid ([a common problem in introductory `C` courses](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/pyramid-pattern)). You have your "get the width" code inside a loop, so it is executed multiple times. You likely meant to only ask for the value once, so you need to move that block of code outside of the `for` loop. The corrected code is included below.

Also, try to avoid using that darned `CS50` library if possible: it's a band-aid that prevents you from learning the C language in all its intricate, beautiful glory.

Lastly, get a good book on C. [*C Primer Plus* by Steve Prata](http://faculty.euc.ac.cy/scharalambous/csc131/books/C%20book%201.pdf) is the unofficial gold standard in intro texts I see mentioned on this site, [and it's literally pennies to purchase a copy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326965). In one of the first chapters, this is one of the exercises.

---

**Updated Code Listing**

---

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Pre-processor Directives
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUF_LEN (256)


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/
bool getBuf(char* buf);


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main (void)
{
    char buf[256] = { 0 };
    int height = 10;
    int width = 10;
    int width_Asterix = 2;
    int i, j, k;

    printf("Enter the Height:");
    if ( !getBuf(buf) ) { return -1; }
    height = atoi(buf);

    printf("Enter the width: ");
    if ( !getBuf(buf) ) { return -1; }
    width = atoi(buf);

    for ( i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = width; j > 0; j-- )
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        width--;

        for ( k = 0; k < width_Asterix; k++ )
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        width_Asterix +=2 ;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
bool getBuf(char* buf)
{
    if (!buf)
    {
        printf("Bad input.\n");
        return false;
    }
    fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, stdin); // Get a string of data
    strtok(buf, "\n");      // Clear out trailing newline
    return true;
}
```

---

**Sample Output**

---

```
Enter the Height:5
Enter the width: 4
    **
   ****
  ******
 ********
**********
```